# Polynomial and convex functions

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, convex-analysis

Consider polynomials $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I have to

1. Give an example of polynomial that isn't convex downward nor convex upward.
2. Give an example of polynomial that is convex downward and convex upward
3. Explain why polynomial with degree 2 is convex downward or convex upward

3.I would say that $(ax^2 + bx + c)^{''}=2a$, $a \neq 0$ so $2a < 0$ or $2a > 0$
but how to do 1. and 2.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A higher degree polynomial that has a convex downward and convex upward part. You can try to construct a third degree polynomial with 3 roots.
2. A line.

Comment: 1.(x-3)(x+3)(x+2) is good, right?

Comment: Right, good job!